# Ajax POST fails on Firefox, works on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

In order to load result from a POST request (which might take up to a minute or two to complete) while showing the user a load screen I am using an Ajax request. This seems to work fine on Chrome, but on Firefox the request fails with an unspecified error after a few seconds, before the server is able to return the response. This appears to happen especially when the server is running on localhost.

```html
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $.post({
         url: "/analyze/",
         data: {
             "data": "data",
         },
         dataType: "html",
         cache: false,
         timeout: 60000,
         success: function(response) {
             $("#container").html(response);
         },
         error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             $("#status").html("<div>Something failed!</div>");
         }
     });
 });
```

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: Did you try to use a vanilla javascript ajax request `XMLHttpRequest()` ?

Comment: Try using `url: "analyze/",`

Comment: Instead of putting `Something failed!` in the status, put `textStatus` and `errorThrown` so you can see the error-details.

Comment: For brevity I removed it, but I do log in console both. textStatus is "error" while errorThrown is empty.

Comment: It seems this might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198411/jquery-ajax-call-not-working-firefox-or-xss-problem

Comment: Using XMLHttpRequest does not seem to make any difference.