# ASP.NET MVC: Redirecting errors in partial to main view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial that I refresh via Ajax.

View Javascript:

```
$("#SelectedId").change(function () {
  var id = $("#SelectedId").val();
  if (id > 0) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/Home/Refresh",
      data: { id: id },
      type: "POST",
      success: function (result) {
        $('#partialHolder').html(result);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Refresh action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Refresh(int id)
{
    HomeViewModel model = new HomeViewModel();
    model.id = id;

    ViewBag.id = model.id;
    PrepareModel(ref model);
    return PartialView("~/Views/PartialView.cshtml", model);
}
```

This works well, except that when an error (such as an HTTP exception) occurs, the error view is sent to the partial when I want it to be shown as the main view.

Error action:

```
public ActionResult Error(string message)
{
  ViewBag.Message = message;
  return View();
}
```

I have tried using Javascript (both in the view and returned by the controller) to redirect the browser, however both are buggy and I assume bad practice.

Comment: Can you show the code of the action refresh?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261617/how-to-handle-model-state-errors-in-ajax-invoked-controller-action-that-returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this in a similar way to [theLaw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737826/asp-net-mvc-redirecting-errors-in-partial-to-main-view/26739496#26739496), by using a try/catch block and the `Content` helper method to return a simple string which triggers a redirect.

Refresh Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Refresh(int id)
{
    try
    {
        HomeViewModel model = new HomeViewModel();
        model.id = id;

        ViewBag.id = model.id;
        PrepareModel(ref model);
        return PartialView("~/Views/PartialView.cshtml", model);
    }
    catch
    {
        return Content("error");
    }
}
```

View Javascript:

```
$("#SelectedId").change(function () {
  var id = $("#SelectedId").val();
  if (id > 0) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/Home/Refresh",
      data: { id: id },
      type: "POST",
      success: function (result) {
        if (result == "error") {
            location.replace("@Url.Action("General", "Error")");
        }
        else {
            ('#partialHolder').html(result);
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as

```
$("#SelectedId").change(function () {
  var id = $("#SelectedId").val();
  if (id > 0) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/Home/Refresh",
      data: { id: id },
      type: "POST",
      success: function (result) {
        $('#partialHolder').html(result);
      },
      error: function(result){
      //call new action
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: The exception in question doesn't seem to affect the return of the partial, only some of the data within it - so the error block is never run.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Error()` returns a complete view (with layout and script/css), you could always try completely overwriting your document:

```
success: function (result) {
   $('#partialHolder').html(result);
},
error: function(xhr) {
   if(xhr.responseText) {
      var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
      newDoc.write(xhr.responseText);
      newDoc.close();
   }
}
```

This will effectively overwrite your entire dom and *will* cause you to lose everything that was on the page.

Credits for document rewrite to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1236378/1705725)

Comment: As with Amit - for some reason the error block doesn't run, even when the exception is thrown.

Comment: @OliWalker What is being returned from your server? Which http status code does it return?

Comment: The partial view is being returned, but a call within it isn't succeeding and causing the error. This will be fixed soon but I want to make sure any future errors are shown in the main view.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

in your action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Refresh(int id)
{
    try
    {
       HomeViewModel model = new HomeViewModel();
       model.id = id;

       ViewBag.id = model.id;
       PrepareModel(ref model);
       return PartialView("~/Views/PartialView.cshtml", model);
   }
   catch
   {
      return PartialView("~/Views/PartialView.cshtml", null);
   }
}
```

so in your ajax success

```
if (result != null) {
   //do your stuff
} else {
    // the controller action returned a partial
    $('#divInYourMain').html("Error 123");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. I don't see how returning a partial with a null model would make `result == null` true?