# jQuery Ajax and error handling

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble finding documentation on the jQuery ajax error. I'd like to create a function that is able to get the name of the web service that was called in order to report the error.

Is there a way in the error function to get the name of the function called?

```
   error: function() {
       //not sure what is available here
   }
```

I'd appreciate any documentation on what's available in the error function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this question: [jQuery Ajax error handling, show custom exception messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377644/jquery-ajax-error-handling-show-custom-exception-messages)

The error function is :

```
error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
  console.dir(xhr);
  console.dir(thrownError);
}
```

Where xhr is the XMLHttpRequest. You can use FireBug's console.dir to get its attributes.