# Call a view with ajax inside jquery file

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a jquery file from which I'd like to call a view. The action at the controller is called Inbox. What is the right way to call this action from the jquery file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very vague and strangely formulated, but i suppose you're looking for jquery assistance.

jQuery offers many ways to do an ajax call. The easiest one is [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) `$('#container').load('path/to/file.html');`

Comment: I was trying doing it this way but the code is incorrect:
$.ajax({
   type: "get",
   url: "planning/inbox",
   data: "s.Site="+SearchSite+"&s.Date="+SearchDate+"",
   });

Comment: @Hallaghan -- you should be careful of the extra trailing comma there, and add a call for success and error handling. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377644/jquery-ajax-error-handling-show-custom-exception-messages) should get you on your way, as you can see how they've handled this.

Answer (score 0):

when calling an ajax, your data must be a json object

```
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "planning/inbox",
  data: { s.Site: searchSite, s.Date: SearchDate }
})
```

Comment: Eh, not so fast. Per [the .ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), your dataType can be JSON, XML, a script, or HTML.

Comment: I called the page this way now:
var SearchDate = $('#s_Date').val();
                var SearchSite = $('#s_Site').val();

                $('#inbox').load('planning/Inbox?s.Site=' + SearchSite + '&s.Date=' + SearchDate + '');

But it takes a long time to retrieve the view like this.