# Why in the world this ajax call is not working

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

```
$(function () {
    $('input#UserName').blur(function () {
        var username = $('input#UserName').val();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "Profile/CheckAvailability",
            data: "username=" + username,               
            success: function (result) {
                //Some code here
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Sorry! We could not receive your feedback at this time.");                
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and the code on Profile controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CheckAvailability(string username)
    {
        bool isAvailable = false;
        //Some code here
        return Json(new {success = isAvailable});
    }
```

Each time `alert("Sorry! We could not receive your feedback at this time.");` is being triggered.

Thanks.

Comment: You have firebug installed? Check out the console tab in it when making this request. What is dataType JsonResult? I looked in to the jquery doc and nothing about that. Available types: xml, json, jsonp, html, text. If the retrieved data json type, then set the dataType : "json".

Comment: I have firebug, I will try in a moment ignore that dataType it was just wrong paste, It definitely does not work with out that.

Comment: Firebug is great - another tool I use all the time is [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).  It'll intercept all HTTP traffic to and from your machine, so it'll work with any browser.  I've found it to be a little more full-featured than Firebug's HTTP debugger, as well.

Comment: Have you tried `data: {"username" : username}`?

Comment: @LukLed: I have just did thanks.

Comment: The problem is that it is trying to access Profile/Profile/CheckAvailability method on controller, that is what firebug console show. How can that be possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few tips:

1. Make sure your controller action is not throwing an exception (especially the part where you say `//Some code here`). This could be verified by stepping through it and debugging.
2. Make sure to always URL encode your request parameters and never use string concatenation:

   ```
   data: { username: username },
   ```
3. Never hardocde urls in your javascript file. Always use Url helpers when dealing with urls (if this is a separate javascript then you could use a global js variable set in your view):

   ```
   url: '<%= Url.Action("Profile", "CheckAvailability") %>',
   ```
4. Use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see what is being sent to and received from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting dataType as "json", because the one you specified isn't valid. Valid dataTypes from jquery documentation: xml, json, jsonp, html, text.

Check out this url about ajax error handling: [jQuery Ajax error handling, show custom exception messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377644/jquery-ajax-error-handling-show-custom-exception-messages)