# Unable to pass JSONObject from JAVA Class to jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have looked at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374981/how-to-pass-a-value-of-a-variable-from-a-java-class-to-the-jsp-page) but I am still unable to retrieve the JSON Object in the jsp. Here's the code in my MyCalendarController.java class:

```
public class MyCalendarController implements Controller{

    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        if("Add".equals(request.getParameter("action"))){
...
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
            jObj.put("test", "Success");
            response.getWriter().write(jObj.toString());
...
         }
     return new ModelAndView("mycalendar", "model", myModel);
}
```

and here's how I'm trying to retrieve it in jsp but the alert always says 'undefined'

```
var queryString = "?action=Add";
    queryString +=  "&t=" + title;
    queryString +=  "&sDT=" + stDate + "T" + stHour + ":" + stMin + ":00";
    queryString +=  "&eDT=" + eDate + "T" + eHour + ":" + eMin + ":00";
$.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "mycalendar.htm" + queryString,
        success: function(response){
                    alert(response.test);
        }
});
```

Note: I am trying to create the JSON Object when the ajax call is made to the class from the jsp. I am new to ajax and javascript so must be doing something wrong... Please help!!!

In the above mentioned code, the **response.responseText** property is 'undefined'. But I tried it another way:

```
var ajaxRequest;

try{                                       
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
}catch (e){
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch (e){
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
 }

 ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        alert(ajaxRequest.responseText);
        alert("test: " + ajaxRequest.test);
     }
}



var queryString = "?action=Add";
queryString +=  "&t=" + title;
queryString +=  "&sDT=" + stDate + "T" + stHour + ":" + stMin + ":00";
queryString +=  "&eDT=" + eDate + "T" + eHour + ":" + eMin + ":00";

ajaxRequest.open("GET", "mycalendar.htm" + queryString, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
```

This way I get the ajaxRequest.responseText but the **alert("test: " + ajaxRequest.test);** still shows **undefined**

Answer (score 1):

```
var a =  '<%=DropDown.returnList()%>';
var countryObj = JSON.parse(a);
var s = $('#selectCountry');  
 for(var val in countryObj) 
      {          
       $('<option />', {value: val, text: countryObj[val]}).appendTo(s); 
      }
```

Comment: Use a static function in Java Class     and import that class in JSP

Answer (score 0):

Try to `alert(response.responseText)`,I am not sure.

Comment: alert(response.responseText) is undefined too...when accessing the object using the first method. In the second method, the ajaxRequest.responseText returns the response. However, the ajaxRequest.test is still undefined. Is this the right way to access the object?
alert("test: " + ajaxRequest.test);
Anyone, any insight... please!!!