# Handling asynchronous saving with the possibility of time-critical errors?

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, tomcat, queue

So, to explain this, I'll start out by going through the application stack.

The system is running JSP with jQuery on top, talking through a controller layer with a service layer, which in turn utilizes a persistence layer implemented in Hibernate.

Now, traditionally, errors like having overlapping contracts has been handled through throwing exceptions up through the layers until they're translated into an error message for the user.

Now I have an object that at any given time can only be tied to one contract. At the moment, when I save a contract, I look at all of these objects and check if they're already covered by an existing contract. However, since multiple clients can be saving at any given time, this introduces the risk of getting past the check on two separate contracts, leading to one object being tied to two contracts at the same time.

To combat this, the idea was to use a queue, put objects into the queue from the main thread, and then have a separate thread take them out one by one, saving them.

However, here's the problem. For one, I would like the user to know that the saving is currently happening, for another, if by accident the scenario before happens, and two contracts with the same object covering the same time is in the queue, the second one will fail, and this needs to be sent back to the user.

My initial attempt was to keep data fields on the object put into the queue, and then check against those in a blocking wait, and then throw an exception or report success based on what happens. That deadlocked the system completely.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction with regards to techniques and patterns I should be using for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really tell why you have a deadlock without seeing your code. I can think of some other options though:

- Poll the thread to see its state (not as good).
- Use some kind of eventing system. You would have an event listener (`OverlappingContractEventListener` perhaps) and then you would trigger the event from the thread when the scenario happens. The event handler would need to persist this information somehow.

If you are going for this approach, then on the client side you will need to poll.

- You can poll a specific controller (using `setInterval` and AJAX) that looks up the corresponding information for the object to see what state its in. This information should have been persisted by your event listener.
- You can use web workers (this is supported in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera. IE will support it in 10) and perform the polling in the background.

There is one other way that doesn't involve eventing. It depends on you figuring out the source of your deadlock though. Once you fix the source of your deadlock you can do one of two things:

- Perform an AJAX call to the controller. The controller will wait for the service to return information. The code to issue feedback to the user will be inside the success handler of your controller.
- Use a web worker to perform the call in the background. The web worker would also perform an AJAX call and wait for the response.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be doing the check for duplicate contracts in the database?  Depending on the case, you can do this with a constraint, trigger, o stored procedure.  If it fails, send an exception up the stack.  That's normally the way to handle things like this.  You can then catch the exception in jQuery and display an error:

[jQuery Ajax error handling, show custom exception messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377644/jquery-ajax-error-handling-show-custom-exception-messages)

Hope this helps.