# ajax jquery simple get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making this simple get request using jquery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://app.asana.com/-/api/0.1/workspaces/",
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
        alert(res);
    }
});
```

It's returning an empty string as a result. If i go to this link in my browser, i get:

```
{"status":401,"error":"Not Authorized"}
```

which is the expected result. So why isn't it working using ajax?
thanks!

Comment: have you tried adding dataType: "jsonp" in there

Comment: @KaiQing, That isn't the problem here at all.  Otherwise, the success handler wouldn't be called.  Besides, the example response isn't a JSONP response.

Comment: @PragmaOnce, Check your headers with a packetsniffer, such as Wireshark.  I suspect you'll find some differences between what is being sent from the browser, and with the AJAX call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to me, this is a cross-domain issue since you're not allowed to make a request to a different domain.

You have to find solutions to this problem:
- Use a proxy script, running on your server that will forward your request and will handle the response sending it to the browser
Or
- The service you're making the request should have JSONP support. This is a cross-domain technique. You might want to read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Answer (score 47):

You can make AJAX requests to applications loaded from the SAME domain and SAME port.

Besides that, you should add `dataType JSON` if you want the result to be deserialized automatically.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://app.asana.com/-/api/0.1/workspaces/",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json', // added data type
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
            alert(res);
        }
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 6):

```
var dataString = "flag=fetchmediaaudio&id="+id;

$.ajax
({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajax.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function(html)
  {
     alert(html);
  }
});
```

Comment: POST and GET is a different HTTP methods, please read some information about HTTP protocol

Answer (score 3):

```
var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "<your URL Here>",
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        "data": {
            "username": "user@company.com",
            "password": "12345678"
        }
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem is that there is no data in the success-function  because the request breaks up with an 401 error in your case and thus has no success.

if you use

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://app.asana.com/-/api/0.1/workspaces/",
        type: 'GET',
         error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
  }
    });
```

there will be your 401 code i think ([this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/377644/1956197)  says so)