# unable to get correct status code in AJAX Error handler

Tags: asp.net, jquery, http-status-codes

I am not able to get correct error code in the error handler of AJAX request. Everytime the error occurs, it returns me statusCode = 500. I tried to set it explicitly in my service as `HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 403;`, but still it gives me status = 500.

This is how my AJAX request looks like:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Services/someSvc.asmx/SomeMethod",
            cache: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data:"{}",
            dataType: "json"
            error: ajaxFailed
        });

        function ajaxFailed(xmlRequest) {
                alert(xmlRequest.status + ' \n\r ' + //This is always 500.
                xmlRequest.statusText + '\n\r' + 
                xmlRequest.responseText);
        }
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: Is you set a server-side break point on SomeMethod does it break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you were almost there, here is an example [WebMethod] that would throw a StatusCode 403.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string HelloWorld(string name)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        return null;
    }
```

Here is the calling jQuery Code.

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var jsonRequest = { name: "Zach Hunter" };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Demo.aspx/HelloWorld',
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonRequest),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data, text)
            {
                $('#results').html(data.d);
            },
            error: function (request, status, error)
            {
                $('#results').html('Status Code: ' + request.status);
            }
        });
    });
```

If you don't return a value as specified in your method signature you'll get a status code 500 returned.

Comment: thanks for the useful answer. After a while i did the same thing in Begin_Request in global.asax and its working fine. Though i am returning 307 as the error code as i want to redirect the user to login page.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
>
> A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives
>   three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a
>   string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional
>   exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second
>   argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and
>   "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the
>   textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal
>   Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array
>   of functions. Each function will be called in turn. Note: This handler
>   is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests. This is an
>   Ajax Event.

So change your code to something more like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Services/someSvc.asmx/SomeMethod",
    cache: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data:"{}",
    dataType: "json",
    error: ajaxFailed (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
}); 

function ajaxFailed(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown + ' \n\r ' + textStatusText);         
}
```

You might also find [this answer provides some additional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377644/jquery-ajax-error-handling-show-custom-exception-messages) info.

Comment: I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: jqXHR is not defined`