# Catch errors in jquery ajax error callback?

Tags: c#, php, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I tend to use a lot of jquery ajax calls to the server side in my applications.

Usually when something goes wrong on the server side ill serialize an errormessage and send as a response (JSON). Something similar to

```
 { "ErrorMessage" : "Something went wrong: " + ex.message }
```

What I would like to know is if there's any way to make errors end up in jquery ajax `error` callback, rather than `success`.

Is there any way to do this? Or should I stick to my old way of handling errors? It doesn't matter if you provide a PHP or ASP.NET + c# example, since im intrested in both. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make them end up in the `error callback` on jQuery. In ASP.NET, all you need to do is to change the `custom errors` section in your web.config to `<customErrors mode="Off" />` **BUT** if you go this route, make sure that you put your web service in a separate folder so that you only do it for your web service calls without turning off this for the entire site; for example:

```
<location Path="/Services"> <!--Your web service lives here -->
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

This way, any exception thrown on your web methods will be handled in the `error callback` in jQuery.

You can either let the exception propagate without caching it on your web method or you can catch it and rethrow a more "user friendly" message.

Comment: Ah ok, but i suppose the errors will be returned as a asp.net default error page as HTML and not JSON?

Comment: `request, status, error` will be returned as JSON objects. You can do something like: `alert(request.responseText);` in your error handler. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377644/jquery-ajax-error-handling-show-custom-exception-messages

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using `Deferred` object in jQuery 1.5+. Ben Nadel has some examples about that, you can have a look here http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2255-Using-jQuery-s-Pipe-Method-To-Change-Deferred-Resolution.htm and here http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2123-Using-Deferred-Objects-In-jQuery-1-5-To-Normalize-API-Responses.htm

Here is a simplified version of its JavaScript code

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "./web_service.cfm",
    dataType: "json"
});

request = request.pipe(

    // Filter the SUCCESS responses from the API.
    function (response) {

        // real success
        if (response.success) {
            return (response);
        }
        else {
            // The response is actually a FAIL even though it
            // came through as a success (200). Convert this
            // promise resolution to a FAIL.
            return (
                $.Deferred().reject(response)
            );
        }
    },

    // Filter the FAIL responses from the API.
    function (response) {
        return ({
            success: false,
            data: null,
            errors: ["Unexpected error: " + response.status + " " + response.statusText]
        });

    }

);


// Now that our API response has been filtered, let's attach
// our success and fail handlers to the promise resolution.
request.then(

    function (response) {
        console.log("Success!!!", response);
    },

    function (response) {
        console.log("Fail!!!", response);
    }

);
```