# How to catch error in ajax callback between success and error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a method call Ajax:

```
function callAjax(url, type, json, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    type: type,
    url: url,
    data: json,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        if (callback) {
            callback(data);
        }
    }
});
}
```

But I don't call back with error in callback.
For example, I can callAjax method like this:

```
 callAjax("http://stackoverflow.com/", "POST", data, function(resp,status){
  if(status.success){
      //code here
    }
     if(status.error){
   //code here
   }
 });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catch errors in jquery ajax error callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589758/catch-errors-in-jquery-ajax-error-callback)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax error handling, show custom exception messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377644/jquery-ajax-error-handling-show-custom-exception-messages)

Comment: You are passing the data response to the callback. But your callback function expects two arguments. So in your success function you should be doing this: callback(data,{success: true}); basd on your implementation. And for error: callback(response,{error: true });

Answer (score 1):

this will work

```
function callAjax(url, type, json, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    type: type,
    url: url,
    data: json,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        if (callback) {
            callback(data,{"success":true});
        }
    },
    error: function(){callback(null,{"error":true});}
 });
}
```

Comment: @dev.knockout, if answer worked for u! then u can Accept the answer.