# Domain lookup using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have two domains(xyz.com and zxy.com). and using jquery ajax call to get the data from one domain.

If first one fails, how do i check and redirect to another domain using javascript.

Comment: You say you have an ajax call that gets data. Where is your code? There is an 'error:' handler for ajax calls in jQuery. Did you google? Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377644/jquery-ajax-error-handling-show-custom-exception-messages

Answer (score 3):

Could you not just use `window.location.host` to find out which domain the user is currently on?

This way you can make the correct ajax call from the start. There is no reason to make a request to the wrong domain, wait for it to fail then make another request.

---

If you do however wish to actually make an `AJAX` request and wait for it to fail then make a different request it would be as follows (this answer is quite verbose on purpose):

```
var firstRequest = $.ajax({
  url: 'http://xyz.com',
  timeout: 5000
});

firstRequest.done(function (data) {

});

firstRequest.fail(function () {

  var anotherRequest = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://xzy.com',
    timeout: 5000
  });

  anotherRequest.done(function (data) {

  });

  anotherRequest.fail(function () {

  });

});
```