# jquery (ajax) redirect to another domain

Tags: jquery, json

I have the jquery json request in the following format:

JSON request:

```
$.getJSON('http://xyz.com',function(result) {});
```

If the request fails(server not responds), how do i redirect to another domain. for example "http://zxy.com".(we maintaining the same code in another server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
function addImage(item) {
 $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
}

    var jqxhr = $.getJSON("http://xyz.com",function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){  //sample
       addImage(item);
    })
    .error(function() { 
              var jqxhrFailover = $.getJSON("http://zzz.com", function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){  //sample
       addImage(item);
    }).error(function(){ alert('both failed!'); });
```

Comment: thanks, But how do i get the results from database, like  "result.username" etc from the second url(if error occurs)

Comment: You need to pass loop the values.

Comment: I tried to put an example above. Try to make it work for one server and then just cascade the calls on the .error()

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a JSON back? If you have a service endpoint it's unlikely you would get a 404. but yes, I believe it would fall in the error() block.

Comment: how do i check the status code in u r code. if server is down(not responding).

Comment: Change the error handling to somethng like this:
.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error " + textStatus);
        console.log("incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);
    })

Answer (score 3):

I think that it may be better to use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), `error` method or `success` if the server tells you based on the response).

Then use this to redirect the browser.

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

$.getJSON() is defined as:

```
jQuery.getJSON=function(url,data,callback){
    return jQuery.get(url,data,callback,"json");
};
```

and as such, fails silently.

To react to errors you'll need to use the $.ajax() function directly which allows you to define an onError handler, as in:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '...',

    contentType:'json',

    success:function(result,stat,xhr){
        ...
    },

    error:function(xhr,opts,err){
        ...
    }
});
```

See [jQuery Ajax error handling, show custom exception messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377644/jquery-ajax-error-handling-show-custom-exception-messages) for further information.