# Redirect to another domain using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery (ajax) redirect to another domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540846/jquery-ajax-redirect-to-another-domain)

I have the jQuery Ajax request in the following format:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'xyz.com',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){}
      );
```

If the request fails(server not responds), how do i redirect to another domain.

I did the same thing by using jquery getJson in the follwing way:

```
$.getJSON('xyz.com',function(result) {})
 .error(
    function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        if (xhr.status == 500) {
            $.getJSON('zxy.com', function(result){});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

Comment: @vishnu I'm not quite sure your question is understandable

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/96245/1273830) answer will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/dYgfG/

**Code**:

```
var domain = "http://xyz.com";

try {
    $.ajax({
        url: domain,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){},
        error: function() {
            alert('ajax error: so redirecting');
            redirectUser();
        }
    });
}
catch(e) {
    alert('exception: so redirecting');
    redirectUser();
}

function redirectUser() {
    window.location.href = domain;        
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. New user? If the answer helped you, mark it as 'accepted' using the green tick next to the title of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use : `crossDomain` property for ajax. Check jquery api [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)