# How to display status description in AJAX?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a page that saves data using jQuery AJAX. On the server side, if the saving process fails, I want to set the StatusDescription of the Response object to "Hey this is Patrick!". The problem is, I can't display the StatusDescription on the client side! It always give me "Internal Server Error". How can I display my custom error message?

Save.ashx

```
Catch ex As Exception
    Transaction.Rollback()
    context.Response.StatusCode = 500
    context.Response.StatusDescription = "Hey this is Patrick!"
End Try
```

AJAX

```
$.ajax
({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Save.ashx',
    data: data,
    async: false,
    success: function(Data, TextStatus, XHR) {
        alert(Data);
    },
    error: function(XHR, TextStatus, ErrorThrown) {
        alert(ErrorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: Internal server error means it is not able to call the server side method.

Comment: @krshekhar No, I'm pretty sure it can. I set the status code to 500 that's why it's Internal Server Error. what I want to do is to change that message through StatusDescription property.

Comment: Interesting that ASP.NET works like that. With WCF web hosting (`WebServiceHost`), `errorThrown` is the same as `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusDescription`.

Answer (score 1):

use XHR.responseText and then see what is the error.
Here is a good link regarding the error of jQuery Call
[jQuery Ajax error handling, show custom exception messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377644/jquery-ajax-error-handling-show-custom-exception-messages)

```
$.ajax
({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Save.ashx',
    data: data,
    async: false,
    success: function(Data, TextStatus, XHR) {
       alert(Data);
     },
     error: function(XHR, TextStatus, ErrorThrown) {
       alert(XHR.responseText);
     }
 });
```

Comment: There is an error of course. What I want to do is to set the status description and show it on the client side. It doesn't matter what the error is.

Comment: Internal server error it's more like generic error you will need the specific error first.

Comment: are you able to call when every thing is ok??

Comment: You misunderstood my goal. I know what the error is, what I want to do is to create a friendly error message for the users, I want to do that by setting `context.Response.StatusDescription`. My problem is, on the client side, I don't know how to retrieve `StatusDescription`.

Comment: It will be easy to use responseText instead but I have pages that use `context.Response.StatusDescription`. Why it's not working?

Comment: I don't know the reason. But I will look for it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19264/discussion-between-dpp-and-krshekhar)

Comment: sorry chat room is not accessible from my organisation

Answer (score 0):

Instead I would return a string message in the response form the server and then you can use it in your `error` function.