# Loading external website view jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Currently, im using the js line below to load website in my HTML page.

```
window.location = 'http://example.com';
```

How can I use jQuery / AJAX to load only if `http://example.com` return HTTP status 200, and display another page if something went wrong like ERROR 500, 504....etc.

Comment: Have you read the docs? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

window.location redirects to the specified url, is dosn't load uri into your HTML Page.

According to your question:
[jQuery Ajax error handling, show custom exception messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377644/jquery-ajax-error-handling-show-custom-exception-messages) shows how to handle ajax errors. In your case the error handling could look like this:

```
 error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    window.location = 'http://example.com';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.example.com"
}).done(function() {
    alert('done')
}).error(function() {
    alert('error')
});
```