# preventing submit based on global error in jquery

Tags: jquery, error-handling

in html:

```
<form action="next.html">
   <!-- tags here -->
   <button id="prev">Prev</button>
   <button id="next">Next</button>
</form>
```

in Javascript:

```
$("form").submit (function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget.id == "next") {
        doPostData();
        // window.location = "next.html";
   } 
   else if (e.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget.id == "prev") {
        window.location = "prev.html";
   }
}
```

I've attached a global errorhandler to `$(document).ajaxError` that parses the code, based on the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377644/jquery-ajax-error-handling-show-custom-exception-messages)

`doPostData()` basically sends a POST request to the server. When this is successful, everything is fine, but when I get an error I don't know how to prevent the form from submitting. The error flashes by and the browser redirects to the 'next' page.

How can I solve this elegantly?

Comment: Have you tried looking if an error appears in the developer console before submitting?

Comment: When I step through the code with Firebug I can see a 'Bad request' response from the server (which is correct).

Comment: Update: not sure what's different between before and now, but now I at least get the error handlers firing and I'm staying on the same page. What remains is: how can I figure out if the errorhandler fired so I can take an appropriate action.

Comment: The errorhandler thing is just for debugging, right? Not something for the final published code? Personally I would probably call doPostData() from console without any form submit and see what error appears.

Comment: @Bemmu Not really, I want nice error handling which puts comprehensible information in a div.message on the page. Errors can occur with 'bad request' and such, but also because the server response with an error message (e.g. 'user does not exist'). When an error occurs I need to stay on the page, if all is ok I need to move on to the next page.

Comment: If you are getting a javascript error, then any script might be broken so preventDefault might not run. To proceed as you want, the default without javascript on has to be for the form not to submit. To do that, maybe take the buttons out from the <form> and do submission from javascript after you have validated the fields.

Comment: @Bemmu Thanks, it works now, not sure what was wrong before. I'll definitely going to try your suggestion when something breaks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just for posterity, I finally figured out what was wrong:

the error handlers fired correctly but the redirect to the next page still happened because there was still a `window.location = "next.html"` available. Similar to removing the comments from the `window.location` line in the code above.

So basic setup, taking into account that the code above only works in FireFox (not in Chrome or Safari):

```
$(document).ajaxError(genericAjaxErrorHandler);

$("#prev").click(function() {
  window.location = "prev.html";
});

$("#next").click(function() {
  doPostData();
});

function doPostData() {
  // actions here

  if (allIsOk) {
      window.location = 'next.html';
  }
}
```

I added a

```
$('form').submit( function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

to be sure, but it might not be necessary.