# Ajax function reloads the page with some parameter on response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on an application where user submit his/her information in tabs...

After .onclick() function, data is submitted to action and saved correctly and returned "success" successfully redirect user to login page...

I have returned two responses so far, "success" and "fail"

But the problem really is, when returning "false"...console.log shows the response correctly, although the work i'd like to perform on "fail" isn't really working..and page reloads with some parameters(i will show it in snapshot)....

Html

```
     <form class="form-horizontal" id="default" name="myform">
     <fieldset title="Step1" class="step" id="default-step-0">

     <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email1" required>
      <label id="err1" class="col-lg-6 control-label" "></label>
       </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="password" name="password1" class="form-control" id="password1" required>
         </div>
          </div>
           <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
           <div class="col-lg-10">
<input type="password" name="confirmpassword1" class="form-control" id="confirmpassword1" required>
            <label id="passMatch" class="col-lg-6 control-label""></label>
           </div>
           </div>
           </fieldset>
           <fieldset title="Step 2" class="step" id="default-step-1">
             //some other input fields on 2nd tab
            </fieldset>
     <input type="button" class="finish btn btn-danger" value="Save" id="btnSubmitAll" />
             </form>
```

Ajax

```
<script>
        $("#btnSubmitAll").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var Email = $('#Email1').val();
                var password = $('#password1').val();
                var confirmpassword = $('#confirmpassword1').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Submit", "Home")',
                    dataType: "JSon",
                    async: false,
                    data: {"Email": Email, "password": password, "confirmpassword": confirmpassword},
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data == "success")
                            {
                            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("login","Home")';
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#err1').html("Email Exist");
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (data, jqXHR, exception) {
                        //some errors in if/else if/else
                        }
                    }
                });
    });
    </script>
```

Please remember, when data == "success", all things go right(returns success after successfull record insertion), but when "fail" returned, console shows it correctly but label not updated with the message and also the whole page reloads with some parameters from the form inputs as can be seen below...

[image]

InAction

```
 if (objIdHelper.IsUserExist(Email))
 {
 return this.Json ("fail");
 }
 else
 {
//some process
return this.Json ("success");
}
```

I am surely missing some logic or doing something stupid, please help....
Any kind of help will be appreciated...thanks for your time

Comment: It sounds like in both cases your `data` (or `data1` based on your below comment) equals success. You console.log is correct because it's outputting data regardless but since the page refreshes, that tells me that `data == 'success'` in both cases. Comment out the code in the `success` block and I bet it won't log anything nor refresh.

Comment: @Leeish yes ofcourse

Comment: Whats I'm say is `$('#err1').html("Email Exist");console.log(data);` is not running because the value of `data` is success

Comment: yes now i understand, thanks for the tip

Comment: how can i show the fail messade, please guide

Comment: You need to fix your action. It must be returning `success` every time for some reason.

Comment: i can fix action code(lots of i/else), but can i do it with exception,,,,i mean if i throw exception with message???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the argumet passed in the **success** callback..Also note that you have wrong understanding for **error** callback. It wont execute if there are any errors in success callback conditions. It is to handle network errors.

Comment: yes i have wrong understanding, no i am returning json("fail") to the function....

Comment: Yes, you can handle those kind of errors in there..[Refer this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377644/jquery-ajax-error-handling-show-custom-exception-messages) for other options.

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement `if (data == "success")` uses `data` instead of `data1` like the function specifies.

Comment: thanks for reply, +1 for effort, i have updated my question....reason for that because i was trying that out with data1 (some one mentioned in other answer that "data" conflicts with some browser)... i will stick with data, thats my mistake to not mention earlier

Comment: You still have to fix the success function. It's listed as data1.