# Ajax return error to call error ajax error call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function which updates my database.. The function works perfectly well and after updating the the database I call the successAlert() function I have created.. however now I want to call the error function in case of error however on testing purposely to break code I still get the successAlert().

**Ajax / Javascript:**

```
var share = "test"
var custid = "test"    

$.ajax({
            url: "assets/ajax/customer-rec.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {UpdateAccount: "yes",custid: custid,share: share},
            success: function(result){
                successAlert()      
            },
            error: function(result){
                errorAlert()    
            }
        });
```

**PHP to update Database**

```
if (isset($_POST['UpdateAccount'])){

    $custid = $_POST['custid'];
    $share = $_POST['share'];
    $query="UPDATE `users` SET `share_ord`='$share' WHERE id= $custid";
    $stmt = mysql_query($query);

    if($stmt === false){
        return false
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you creating a failure? Did you rename "assets/ajax/customer-rec.php"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

return false is not an error. If you want to send the error use headers like

```
header('X-PHP-Response-Code: 404', true, 404);
```

you can call the same errorAlert()  function in success also so that

```
$.ajax({
        url: "assets/ajax/customer-rec.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {UpdateAccount: "yes",custid: custid,share: share},
        success: function(result){
            if(result === false){
               errorAlert()
            } else  {
               successAlert()
            }      
        },
        error: function(result){
            errorAlert()    
        }
    });
```

Comment: also worth a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377644/jquery-ajax-error-handling-show-custom-exception-messages

Answer (score 0):

To get error you need to return the status code '404' from the php function which is serving your request.

Answer (score 0):

The `error` callback is fired when the server returns a HTTP status code that indicates an error, as such you should send one, ex `HTTP 500`

```
if($stmt === false){
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Server error');
}
```

See here a [list of HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) status codes

Answer (score 0):

.ajax() will call on success method because, once your request is processed successfully by the server then it reruns HTTP_OK to the client and if .ajax not received HTTP_OK, then it will call error. According to your code, it will call success, because url is exists and server will send HTTP_OK to the browser.
If you want to generate `error:` then give wrong url or disconnect internet or simply change

In PHP:

```
if($stmt === false){
      //If you want really generate some http error.
       header('X-PHP-Response-Code: 500', true, 500);
       exit(0);
      //or else continue as per code
      // return false;   
    }
```

In your JS:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "assets/ajax/customer-rec.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {UpdateAccount: "yes",custid: custid,share: share},
        success: function(result){
            if(!result){
               showErrorAlert()
            } else  {
               showSuccessAlert()
            }      
        },
        error: function(result){
            showErrorAlert()    
        }
    });
```