# jQuery ajax fail error message unclear

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

Many times my jQuery.ajax() function calling the .fail() function and it contains only this data:

error: "error"
 errorThrown: "error"

Is there a way to get some more relevant information about why it failed?

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/377644/4053389)