# Setting a response code in a MVC5 ApiController that returns json

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have something like this using MVC5:

```
Namespace Controllers
Public Class WorkflowsController Inherits ApiController

    <HttpPost>
    <ActionName("SaveComment")>
    Public Function PostComment(id As String, Optional comment As String = "")
        Try
            Dim status As ApiResponse = SomeClass.AddComment(id, comment)

            Return Me.Json(status)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Me.Json(New ApiResponse With {.ErrorMessage = ex.Message})
        End Try
    End Function    
End Class
End Namespace
```

It works fine, and as you can see, it returns a json object to the browser in both normal and error conditions.  In the case of the exception, how can I set the response code to 500 as well as returning the ErrorMessage as a json object?

Comment: Here is a C# version of it [Show exception message to client side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46532062/40521)  Remove the `if` condition for  the `X-Requested-With` header and it should work for all requests

Comment: Why return a 500 response code if your ApiResponse already handles error messages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could execute a [HttpStatusCodeResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult(v=vs.118).aspx) before returning your [JsonResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx) :

```
    Try
        Dim status As ApiResponse = SomeClass.AddComment(id, comment)

        Return Me.Json(status)
    Catch ex As Exception
        (New HttpStatusCodeResult(500)).ExecuteResult(ControllerContext)
        Return Me.Json(New ApiResponse With {.ErrorMessage = ex.Message})
    End Try
```