# AJAX works on localhost, but doesn't on live server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Below code works on localhost, but not on live server.

**MAIN EDIT:**

> Only 1 thing remains which is not working:

On `AJAX` success this will being executed:

```
$(".FixedDiv").addClass("panel-danger");
setTimeout(close, 500);
$("#label_" + res[2]).html(data.score_result);
$("#monitoring_score").html(data.calculated_score);
```

How ever, the `label`(for example) is not being updated. The `label` needs to be updated by the score which is given (data.score_result).

**Ajax code:**

```
$('.rating').on('rating.change', function () {
  var rating_id = $(this).attr('id');
  var res = rating_id.split("_");

  var comment = $("#comments_" + res[2]).val();
  var score = $("#item_score_" + res[2]).val();

  var post = 'controller=QualityMonitoring&task=setScore&monitor_id='
    + <?php echo $query['monitor_id']; ?>
    + '&q=' + res[2] + '&item_score=' + score + '&comment=' + comment;

  $.ajax({
    url: "controller.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: post,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
      saveScore();
    },
    success: function (data) {
      $(".FixedDiv").addClass("panel-danger");
      setTimeout(close, 500);
      $("#label_" + res[2]).html(data.score_result);
      $("#monitoring_score").html(data.calculated_score);
    }
  });
});
```

When I put `alert('test');` above the `$.ajax({` code it shows 'test'. When I put the alert INSIDE (just below) the `$.ajax({` code, it does not show the alert.

**saveScore function:**

```
function saveScore() {
  var docHeight = $(document).height();

  $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");

  $("#overlay")
    .height(docHeight)
    .css({
      'opacity': 0.4,
      'position': 'absolute',
      'top': 0,
      'left': 0,
      'background-color': 'black',
      'width': '100%',
      'z-index': 5000
    });
}
```

**Results/info:**

1. `alert(post);` gives me the correct data result.
2. `saveScore` is executed, but won't close afterwards (`setTimeout)`.
3. `#label` and `#monitoring_score` are not being updated like it has to do.
4. using `jquery-3.1.1`.

I'm distraught on how to solve this. Anyone has an idea on how to fix?

**Extra:**

@Teemu:

> Add an error handler to the AJAX call too, most likely it's the
>   server-side which passes an error instead of data. Or open Network tab
>   from the DevTools, and see if you're actually getting 200 OK message
>   and the data.

**Edit 1:** *(Whole javascript code):*

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".nav-tabs a").click(function () {
            $(this).tab('show');
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.summernote').summernote({
            height: 450,   //set editable area's height
            toolbar: [
                ['view', ['fullscreen']],
                ['help', ['help']]
            ],
            codemirror: { // codemirror options
                theme: 'monokai'
            }

        });
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        $('.nvt').on('click', function () {
            // get the id:
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var res = id.split("_");

            // Reset rating:
            var rating_input = "item_score_" + res[1];
            $('#' + rating_input).rating('update', 0);

            var comment = $("#comments_" + res[1]).val();
            var score = 0;

            var post = 'controller=QualityMonitoring&task=setScore&monitor_id=' + <?php echo $query['monitor_id']; ?> +'&q=' + res[1] + '&item_score=' + score + '&comment=' + comment;

            $.ajax({
                url: "controller.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: post,
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function () {
                    saveScore();
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $(".FixedDiv").addClass("panel-danger");
                    setTimeout(closediv, 500);
                    $("#label_" + res[1]).html(data.score_result);
                    $("#monitoring_score").html(data.calculated_score);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    $(".FixedDiv").addClass("panel-danger");
                    setTimeout(closediv, 500);
                    $("#label_" + res[1]).html(data.score_result);
                    $("#monitoring_score").html(data.calculated_score);
                }
            });

        });

        $('.rating').on('rating.change', function () {
            var rating_id = $(this).attr('id');
            var res = rating_id.split("_");

            var comment = $("#comments_" + res[2]).val();
            var score = $("#item_score_" + res[2]).val();

            var post = 'controller=QualityMonitoring&task=setScore&monitor_id=' + <?php echo $query['monitor_id']; ?> +'&q=' + res[2] + '&item_score=' + score + '&comment=' + comment;

            $.ajax({
                url: "controller.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: post,
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function (data) {
                    saveScore();
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $(".FixedDiv").addClass("panel-danger");
                    setTimeout(closediv, 500);
                    $("#label_" + res[2]).html(data.score_result);
                    $("#monitoring_score").html(data.calculated_score);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log("ERROR: ", data);
                }
            });

        });

        $('.savecomment').on('blur', function () {
            var comment_id = $(this).attr('id');
            var res = comment_id.split("_");

            var commentraw = $("#comments_" + res[1]).val();
            var comment = encodeURIComponent(commentraw);

            var post = 'controller=QualityMonitoring&task=setComment&monitor_id=' + <?php echo $query['monitor_id']; ?> +'&q=' + res[1] + '&comment=' + comment;

            $.ajax({
                url: "controller.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: post,
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.result == 666) {
                        $("#comments_" + res[1]).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
                    }
                }
            });

        });
    });

    $(document).on('change', '.btn-file :file', function () {
        var input = $(this),
                numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
                label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
        input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btn-file :file').on('fileselect', function (event, numFiles, label) {

            var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
                    log = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : label;

            if (input.length) {
                input.val(log);
            } else {
                if (log) alert(log);
            }

        });
    });

    function closediv() {
        $(document).unbind("keyup");
        $("#overlay").fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $("#overlay").remove();
            $(".FixedDiv").removeClass("panel-danger");
        });

    }

    function saveScore() {
        var docHeight = $(document).height();

        $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");

        $("#overlay")
                .height(docHeight)
                .css({
                    'opacity': 0.4,
                    'position': 'absolute',
                    'top': 0,
                    'left': 0,
                    'background-color': 'black',
                    'width': '100%',
                    'z-index': 5000
                });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $sidebar = $(".FixedDiv"),
                $window = $(window),
                offset = $sidebar.offset(),
                topPadding = 55;

        $window.scroll(function () {
            if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                $sidebar.stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                });
            } else {
                $sidebar.stop().animate({
                    marginTop: 24
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: don't use alert, check the console

Comment: Will do, one sec. Do you want me to `console.log(data);` ?

Comment: Alert! It was 2018... Trivial to figure out the problem once you open devtools and check network tab.

Comment: Are you able to `console.log(data)` on success function?

Comment: no, i want you to check if there is error inside the console

Comment: @TemaniAfif, no error.

Comment: you uploaded all the files, cleared all your cache, the structure is similar to localhost, no server issue, etc ?

Comment: your code is missing the error block to detect the issue,  see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377644/jquery-ajax-error-handling-show-custom-exception-messages

Comment: @Eddie, console.log(data); inside the $.ajax doesn't give result in the console. It seems the $.ajax is not being executed. Outside the $.ajax i receive results in the console.

Comment: Just so that you don't catch yourself saying one day "I don't use alert just because a guy on SO told me not to": using `alert` is a bad idea because if you ever forget one alert from dev to prod it's going to impact your program and user experience since an ugly message will appear for no reason, `console.log` won't.

Comment: Add an error handler to the AJAX call too, most likely it's the server-side which passes an error instead of data. Or open Network tab from the DevTools, and see if you're actually getting 200 OK message and the data.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat, thanks I will edit my question with your information. But the alert was just to see if the script actually executes the function. From now on I'll use console.log ;-)!

Comment: @RicardoPontual, added error. But the `#label` and `#monitoring_score` are not being executed. And it seems error is being executed instead of success.

Comment: @Teemu See comment above ^

Comment: Network errors are not logged to the console, you need to take a look at the Network tab.

Comment: @Teemu, Console network gives me this: name = link to current page, status = 200, type = document, initator = other. All other requests are status 200 as well. First time im using network, so if you need anything just ask.

Comment: It seems 50% is solved. The layer from `saveScore` is being updated. Only thing left is to have the `#label` and `#monitoring_score` being edited. `saveScore` is fixed by adding error.

Comment: it can be a CORS  problem . check your console for errors

Comment: @MOHAMMEDYASSINEChabli no error is shown. Meawhile: just `#label` and `#monitoring_score` is not being edited.

Comment: @Teemu `console.log(ajaxOptions);` gives me this: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at Nb (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
    at A (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)

Comment: It looks like your server sends HTML instead of JSON then, or the JSON is malformed. Apart from that, [`close`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) is a native DOM method, you should not override it, use another name for the function, especially, if it is a global function.

Comment: @Teemu Thank for all your help man, i really appreciate it. I've changed the `dataType` to 'text'. Now it seems `success` is being executed instead of `error`. I also changed 'close' to 'closediv'. Just this part does not work: `$("#label_" + res[1]).html(data.score_result);` and  `$("#monitoring_score").html(data.calculated_score);` Do you have an idea? I will keep searching meanwhile on the internet for sure

Comment: Please check the data you're getting from the server. Obviously you need JSON to be send, that's why those parts are not working. When you set datatype to text, you'll receive a string, and naturally that won't have the properties you're retrieving from the send data.

Comment: @Teemu Check! This is what I receive from the server: `{"calculated_score":7.7,"score_result":"1.17 pts"}`. This is what 'data' in ajax contains.

Comment: Now I'm dropping off the wagon ... That looks valid JSON, and everything should be OK. I can't understand, how jQuery found `<` from the response ..?

Comment: It's maybe rather a hack, but you could parse the string to JSON with `JSON.parse()` and then use the created object as data ...

Comment: Unfortunately I've got to go. I'll test your 'hack' tomorrow and I wil let you know the results! Thanks for your time thus far.

Comment: @Teemu ajax says its not a json format... This is my controller who creates the json with data: `public function setScore()
 {
  $data['calculated_score'] = 'some calculation';
  $data['score_result']     = 'some calculation';

  echo json_encode($data);
  exit();
 }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164814/discussion-between-ronnie-oosting-and-teemu).

Comment: Please join this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167740/discussion-ajax-works-on-localhost-but-doesnt-on-live-server) room

Comment: What kind of servers do you use for localhost and live? Are they different types?

Comment: i just read the last part of the discussion and i'm curious about : `statically test the controller output` , how are you testing it exactly ? like .. an url ? an app like `postman` ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of any of the other hundreds of ajax questions with an error callback being called with a parseerror. Your server isn't returning valid json. **Make it return valid json**. The localhost vs live server is irrelevant to the ajax, if you want to figure out how to fix that, ask a different question with the required information to debug that particular problem. the client-side code isn't related to that problem.

Comment: use developer tools -> Network to trace the error. post it here.

Comment: Only 2 things can cause "#Label_"  not to update. Check if res[2] is undefined, or a not expected value. check that data.score_result has a value.

Comment: @RonnieOosting is the local a linux server and the live a windows? what kind of operating systems do they use? How do you upload the code, ftp?

Comment: Where is your `close` function calling from here `setTimeout(close, 500);` ?

Comment: @JannesBotis live is linux, local is windows. Upload to ftp through bitbucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your PHP code valid and not throwing extra code which is messing up your JSON object. When there is a notice the JSON object becomes a string instead of a JSON string and then javascript can't parse it anymore.

Please make a new clean controller without any other code, post the data again and then check what is happening. Never return data but echo data with an exit.

Javascript and Code looks valid but somewhere else in your MVC may throw HTML code in the exit statement or generating it before you enter the controller which is required to return the data.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I've edited the code and posted it into a new clean controller. It seems it's working now. Thanks a lot. I've been searching for like two weeks for a fix. It seems the current controller is to big and somewhere it corrupts the output. I'll mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

1. after function saveScore() add: 
   `var close = function() { $('#overlay').remove(); };`
2. after `success: function (data) {}` remove last comma

Answer (score 1):

I think a few of the other posters are on to something about the invalid JSON,

I would add however, this is something I like to do for JSON

```
<?php
   ob_start(); //turn on output buffering

   //...other code


$debug = ob_get_clean();
$response['debug'] = $debug; //comment this when live in production

header('Content-type: application/json');

echo json_encode($response);
```

What this does is turn on output buffering.  Which traps any output and buffers it.  This includes warnings, notices, echo, and print stuff.  Then it stuffs it into the response as debug and forwards it to the client.

Obviously you would not want to do this on live production server, but you can easily comment it out. It can be a security issue to include some errors and stack trace information to the client.  But for debugging purposes it works great.

The problem with JSON is if you are checking the value of something somewhere (printing it) or have any notices it will muck up your JSON.  For example

```
 printed content
 {"foo":"bar"}
```

So this takes away that  problem entirely (assuming you output buffer before printing anything) like so:

```
 {"foo":"bar", "debug":"printed content"}
```

And now you have valid JSON, and as a side bonus you can print out your debug info by simply doing

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "controller.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: post,
     cache: false,
     dataType: "json",
     beforeSend: function () {
       saveScore();
     },
     success: function (data) {
          if(data.debug) console.log(data.debug);
     }
 });
```

It's simple and effective.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, ill test it tomorrow! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an error handler to your Ajax function and see what it returns:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "controller.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: post,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
      saveScore();
    },
    success: function (data) {
      $(".FixedDiv").addClass("panel-danger");
      setTimeout(close, 500);
      $("#label_" + res[2]).html(data.score_result);
      $("#monitoring_score").html(data.calculated_score);
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log("ERROR: ", data);
    }
  });
```

Share the result with us so we can trouble shoot your issue and help you.

Comment: ERROR:  
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort
:
ƒ (a)
always
:
ƒ ()
catch
:
ƒ (a)
done
:
ƒ ()
fail
:
ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders
:
ƒ ()
getResponseHeader
:
ƒ (a)
overrideMimeType
:
ƒ (a)
pipe
:
ƒ ()
progress
:
ƒ ()
promise
:
ƒ (a)
readyState
:
4
responseText
:
"<!doctype html>LOTS OF HTML CODE</html>"
setRequestHeader
:
ƒ (a,b)
state
:
ƒ ()
status
:
200
statusCode
:
ƒ (a)
statusText
:
"OK"
then
:
ƒ (b,d,e)
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: I'll take the long answer to anyone looking at this answer can understand what is happening.

The readyState 4 and status 200 mean the HTTP request was successful but the data parsing probably had an error.

Now we troube shoot again. On your Ajax function change your datatype to jsonp instead of json and test it again to see if it throws an error or not.

Comment: Thanks Mario. Do you have any idea what to do?

Comment: @RonnieOosting sorry, the first answer was incomplete. check the comment before yours I've updated it with more information.

Comment: {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort
:
ƒ (a)
always
:
ƒ ()
catch
:
ƒ (a)
done
:
ƒ ()
fail
:
ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders
:
ƒ ()
getResponseHeader
:
ƒ (a)
overrideMimeType
:
ƒ (a)
pipe
:
ƒ ()
progress
:
ƒ ()
promise
:
ƒ (a)
readyState
:
4
responseText
:
"<!doctype html>LOTS OF HTML CODE</html>"
setRequestHeader
:
ƒ (a,b)
state
:
ƒ ()
status
:
200
statusCode
:
ƒ (a)
statusText
:
"OK"
then
:
ƒ (b,d,e)
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: and: `VM3580:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at p (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.globalEval (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at text script (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
    at Nb (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
    at A (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)`

Comment: want to chat here?: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167740/discussion-ajax-works-on-localhost-but-doesnt-on-live-server that might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wrapping your js code in [$(document).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) ?

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

Try enclosing everything in

```
$(function(){
//your code here
})
```

Like this:

```
$(function(){
$('.rating').on('rating.change', function () {
  var rating_id = $(this).attr('id');
  var res = rating_id.split("_");

  var comment = $("#comments_" + res[2]).val();
  var score = $("#item_score_" + res[2]).val();

  var post = 'controller=QualityMonitoring&task=setScore&monitor_id='
    + <?php echo $query['monitor_id']; ?>
    + '&q=' + res[2] + '&item_score=' + score + '&comment=' + comment;

  $.ajax({
    url: "controller.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: post,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
      saveScore();
    },
    success: function (data) {
      $(".FixedDiv").addClass("panel-danger");
      setTimeout(close, 500);
      $("#label_" + res[2]).html(data.score_result);
      $("#monitoring_score").html(data.calculated_score);
    }
  });
});

function saveScore() {
  var docHeight = $(document).height();

  $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");

  $("#overlay")
    .height(docHeight)
    .css({
      'opacity': 0.4,
      'position': 'absolute',
      'top': 0,
      'left': 0,
      'background-color': 'black',
      'width': '100%',
      'z-index': 5000
    });
}

});
```

Comment: Hi Jorge, Ill make an edit with my JS code. One second.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted, the comments below and the discussion ( actually was very helpful to jump to this conclusion ) .. i can point a couple of things, but first :

adding `error_reporting(0);` in the begining of the `controller` right after `<?php` should solve your problem. ( if my guess is correct and it's just a notice, not an actual error)

i'm guessing that you already have this in your `localhost` 's `php.ini` and on the live server you have the default `error_reporting = E_ALL`, due to two different installations of `php`.

there's probably somewhere in the `controller` a `notice` of an undefined index or something, and `php` is trying to let you know by outputting this :

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: ...
{"calculated_score":10,"score_result":"1.75 pts"}
```

it starts with a `<` and that's where this comes from

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

the `$.ajax` is unable to parse this because you have `dataType="json"` and this means that it is expecting a valid `json` back from the server, so you get the `200` status because the request was successful with no errors and `console.log(data)` will be empty because it was unable to parse it.

a simple way to reproduce this is creating a test `php` file and send the request to it instead of `controller.php` like :

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0); // try with and without this line.

    $data = [
        'city' => 'Montreal',
        'Country' => 'Canada'
    ];

    echo $_GET['something']; // this will trigger a notice of undefined index something

    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

you can remove `dataType:"json"` and put `console.log(data)` in the `success function` and look in the console to see what the server is really telling you.

but here's something that bugs me ..

`var post = 'controller=QualityMonitoring&task=setScore&monitor_id='`

this looks like a query string you use for `GET` requests but you have `type:"POST"` in your `ajax` request ..

i don't know how you're handling this in the `controller` but it should be `type:"GET"` to send data like this, but if you want to send the data with `POST` then `var post` should be an object, ( this could be the problem as it defaults to `GET` when not set and in the controller there's a `$_GET['task']` instead of `$_POST['task']` or vise-versa ) so here's a snippet to convert the query string to a `json` :

```js
function QueryStringToJSON(str) {
 var pairs = str.split('&');
 var result = {};
 pairs.forEach(function (pair) {
  pair = pair.split('=');
  var name = pair[0]
  var value = pair[1]
  if (name.length)
   if (result[name] !== undefined) {
    if (!result[name].push) {
     result[name] = [result[name]];
    }
    result[name].push(value || '');
   } else {
    result[name] = value || '';
   }
 });
 return (result);
}

var string = 'controller=QualityMonitoring&task=setScore&monitor_id=5&q=blah&item_score=99&comment=hello';
var obj = QueryStringToJSON(string);

console.log(obj);
```

i hope this helps or at least gives you an idea, and Good Luck.

Comment: Hi Taki, thank you for your time. `var post = 'controller=QualityMonitoring&task=setScore&monitor_id='` receives a json format.

Comment: There is only 1 problem left... The data is being saved, just the success part in the ajax needs to be executed. The div's need to be changed with new content. For example: `$("#label_" + res[2]).html(data.score_result);` inside the `$('.rating').on('rating.change', function () {` function.

Comment: if your controller is working fine then removing `dataType="json"` should get the `success` function to work because it won't have to parse the data it got from the server, but you won't have `data.score_result` , if adding`error_reporting(0);` to your controller didn't do the trick then post a screenshot of the `LOTS OF HTML CODE` you're having in the response.