# How to get HTML of a URL which response with a 404 error in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, web-scraping

Suppose I am trying to fetch page which throws a 404 not found response yet shows an html page. I want to get html elements of that page using jQuery.

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/page/2/',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){ 
        console.log($(data).find('#reviews .card').text());
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log($(data).find('.not-found').text());
    }
});
```

I get this message in console window

```
GET http://example.com/page/2/ 404 ()
```

Suppose I wanna grab the title from the page which says "Page does not exist." and the JSON object data returned between the `<script> </script>` of the html of the page, how should I do it?

Comment: I believe you can use fetch, it doesn't reject the promise on 400 class errors

Comment: I dont know how true this is anymore but historically some browsers have consumed 404 pages so you wouldnt be able to see the contents regardless.

Comment: Assuming you aren't blocked by CORS, you can get the HTML from the `responseText` property of the jqXHR object in the `error` handler: `data.responseText`. Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/xnfj0asr/. You can then retrieve the `title` from this. Retrieving the JSON will be much harder though, to the point where I'd suggest finding another, much better way.

Comment: @Luca would it return an html page so I can grab an element?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks! That worked. Can you suggest me a better way to retrieve the JSON data?

Comment: If it's possible make another AJAX call to retrieve it. Otherwise you'll have to somehow hack the responseText string to retrieve the JS from within the page then probably have to `eval()` it to turn it in to executable logic. Ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @RoryMcCrossan I used `responseText` and rewrote the code again to something like this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/page/2/',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){ 
        var html = $(data);
        console.log(html.find('#reviews .card').text());
    },
    error: function(data) {
        var html = $(data.responseText)
        console.log(html.find('.not-found').text());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean this?

[jQuery Ajax error handling, show custom exception messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377644/jquery-ajax-error-handling-show-custom-exception-messages)

```
    success: function(){
       ...
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr); // I believe this returns an object
        console.log(xhr.statusText); //"Not Found" 
        console.log(xhr.status); //404
    },
});
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to grab the html of the page which I got through `responseText`

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem:

```
error: function (err) {
    console.log(err); // This will throw the whole error.
    console.log(err.response); // This will throw the object you want to modify
    console.log(error.response.status); // This will throw the status code you want!
},
```

Hope this works!

Comment: `console.log(err.response);` gives undefined, maybe you mean err.responseText.
`console.log(error.response.status)` that didn't work so I tried this `console.log(error.status)` and it worked.