# Unable to display Success message after sending an email from the contact form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, contacts

I'm unable to see the "message sent successfully" after clicking on the Send button even though it's mentioned here on php: if( $sendEmail == true ):
                echo '{ "alert": "success", "message": "' . $message_success . '" }';

The code is from a template, here is the HTML, PHP and JS code bellow:

HTML:

```
<div class="contact-form">
    <form class="text-white mb-0" id="cf" name="cf" action="include/sendemail.php" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-process"></div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group error-text-white">
                    <input type="text" id="cf-name" name="cf-name" placeholder="Nom" class="form-control fc-bordered fc-light required">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group error-text-white">
                    <input type="email" id="cf-email" name="cf-email" placeholder="Adresse E-mail" class="form-control fc-bordered fc-light required">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 mb-4">
                <div class="form-group error-text-white">
                    <textarea name="cf-message" id="cf-message" placeholder="Message" class="form-control fc-bordered fc-light required" rows="7"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 d-none">
                <input type="text" id="cf-botcheck" name="cf-botcheck" value="" class="form-control fc-bordered fc-light" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <button class="btn btn-white" type="submit" id="cf-submit" name="cf-submit">Send Message</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="contact-form-result pt-1"></div>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

// If you intend you use SMTP, uncomment next line
//require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

$toemails = array();

$toemails[] = array(
'email' => 'xxxx', // Your Email Address
'name' => 'xxxx' // Your Name
 );

// Form Processing Messages
$message_success = 'We have successfully received your Message and 
will get Back to you as soon as possible.';

$mail = new PHPMailer();

// If you intend you use SMTP, add your SMTP Code after this Line-

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
if( $_POST['cf-email'] != '' ) {

    $name = isset( $_POST['cf-name'] ) ? $_POST['cf-name'] : '';
    $email = isset( $_POST['cf-email'] ) ? $_POST['cf-email'] : '';
    $subject = isset( $_POST['cf-subject'] ) ? $_POST['cf-subject'] : '';
    $message = isset( $_POST['cf-message'] ) ? $_POST['cf-message'] : '';

    $subject = isset($subject) ? $subject : 'New Message From Contact Form';

    $botcheck = $_POST['cf-botcheck'];

    if( $botcheck == '' ) {

        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $mail->SetFrom( $email , $name );
        $mail->AddReplyTo( $email , $name );
        foreach( $toemails as $toemail ) {
            $mail->AddAddress( $toemail['email'] , $toemail['name'] );
        }
        $mail->Subject = $subject;

        $name = isset($name) ? "Name: $name<br><br>" : '';
        $email = isset($email) ? "Email: $email<br><br>" : '';
        $message = isset($message) ? "Message: $message<br><br>" : '';

        $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? '<br><br><br>This Form was submitted from: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

        $body = "$name $email $message $referrer";

        $mail->MsgHTML( $body );
        $sendEmail = $mail->Send();

        if( $sendEmail == true ):
            echo '{ "alert": "success", "message": "' . $message_success . '" }';
        else
            echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Email could not be sent due to some Unexpected Error. Please Try Again later.<br /><br />Reason:<br />' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '" }';
        endif;
    } else {
        echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Bot Detected.! Clean yourself Botster.!" }';
    }
} else {
    echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Please Fill up all the Fields and Try Again." }';
}
} else {
echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "An unexpected error occured. 
Please Try Again later." }';
}

?>
```

JS:

```
 function ln_contactForm() {
    var contactForm = $('.contact-form');
    if( contactForm.length < 1 ){ return true; }

    contactForm.each( function(){
        var el = $(this),
            elResult = el.find('.contact-form-result');

        el.find('form').validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                elResult.fadeOut( 500 );

                $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                    target: elResult,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function( data ) {
                        elResult.html( data.message ).fadeIn( 500 );
                        if( data.alert != 'error' ) {
                            $(form).clearForm();
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                elResult.fadeOut( 500 );
                            }, 5000);
                        };
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is not working. Have you tried to pop the errors ? I recommand you to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377644/jquery-ajax-error-handling-show-custom-exception-messages

Answer (score 0):

```
There might be a syntax error in your below code 

if( $sendEmail == true ):
        echo '{ "alert": "success", "message": "' . $message_success . '" }';
    <b>else</b>
        echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Email could not be sent due to some Unexpected Error. Please Try Again later. Reason:' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '" }';
endif;    

Correct syntax of if else statement is

 if( $sendEmail == true ):
     else :
 endif;    
Please fix it in your code, and then try.
```

Comment: Yeah That was a syntax error, I fixed it, but it's still the same problem. The form sends messages but no Success message shows after sending..

Comment: What message is recieved

Comment: It displays no message, but I notice a small change in the margin of website after clicking send, and that's it. however the mailer works just fine